# Bonfire Database error

Tags: php, codeigniter, settings, bonfire

I am using **ciBonfire** for the first time, it looks very good and promising to kick start the development and stuff.

The installation  went good without a problem. But when I try to use its admin panel to save new settings, it gives me an error as below:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 1440

Backtrace:
```

I have raised the issue in Bonfire forums but it seems no one is active there.
It will be really helpful if somebody can take a look at this.

> Error Number: 1048
>
> Le champ 'value' ne peut être vide (null)
>
> UPDATE `bf_settings` SET `value` = CASE WHEN `name` = 'site.title'
>   THEN 'My Bonfire' WHEN `name` = 'site.system_email' THEN
>   'admin@mybonfire.com' WHEN `name` = 'site.status' THEN '1' WHEN `name`
>   = 'site.list_limit' THEN '25' WHEN `name` = 'auth.allow_register' THEN 1 WHEN `name` = 'auth.user_activation_method' THEN 0 WHEN `name` =
>   'auth.login_type' THEN 'email' WHEN `name` = 'auth.use_usernames' THEN
>   '1' WHEN `name` = 'auth.allow_remember' THEN 1 WHEN `name` =
>   'auth.remember_length' THEN 1209600 WHEN `name` =
>   'auth.use_extended_profile' THEN 0 WHEN `name` =
>   'auth.allow_name_change' THEN 1 WHEN `name` =
>   'auth.name_change_frequency' THEN '1' WHEN `name` =
>   'auth.name_change_limit' THEN '1' WHEN `name` =
>   'auth.password_min_length' THEN '8' WHEN `name` =
>   'auth.password_force_numbers' THEN NULL WHEN `name` =
>   'auth.password_force_symbols' THEN NULL WHEN `name` =
>   'auth.password_force_mixed_case' THEN NULL WHEN `name` =
>   'auth.password_show_labels' THEN 0 WHEN `name` = 'password_iterations'
>   THEN '8' WHEN `name` = 'site.show_profiler' THEN 1 WHEN `name` =
>   'site.show_front_profiler' THEN 1 WHEN `name` = 'site.languages' THEN
>   'a:3:{i:0;s:7:\"english\";i:1;s:7:\"persian\";i:2;s:10:\"portuguese\";}'
>   ELSE `value` END WHERE `name`
>   IN('site.title','site.system_email','site.status','site.list_limit','auth.allow_register','auth.user_activation_method','auth.login_type','auth.use_usernames','auth.allow_remember','auth.remember_length','auth.use_extended_profile','auth.allow_name_change','auth.name_change_frequency','auth.name_change_limit','auth.password_min_length','auth.password_force_numbers','auth.password_force_symbols','auth.password_force_mixed_case','auth.password_show_labels','password_iterations','site.show_profiler','site.show_front_profiler','site.languages')
>
> Filename: E:/wamp/www/mpa/bonfire/core/BF_Model.php
>
> Line Number: 622

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by updating ( V0.8.0 to V0.8.1 ) 
After updating, settings work fine now.

you can see it here my post for more info :
http://forums.cibonfire.com/discussion/comment/4519/#Comment_4519

Can see last changelog here : 
https://github.com/ci-bonfire/Bonfire/blob/master/bonfire/docs/changelog.md

Make sure you are up to date :)